# show the csv file genered by html/javascript in horizontal format instead of vertical

Tags: javascript, html, csv

My below code outputs the csv file one below the other like

> Date,Value
>
> inp2:val2
>
> 09172013, 1
>
> 08172013, 2
>
> inp3:val3
>
> 09172013, 10.1
>
> 08172013, 20

Here the first column is the date and second the value

How can I make it to show like
Date               inp2                 inp3
09172013,          1 ,                  10.1
08172013,          2 ,                   20

Thanks

The code

```
<html">
<head>
    <title>JSON to CSV</title>
    <script src="json.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var str = '';
    var json3 = 
        {"inp2:val2": {"data": [[09172013, 1], [08172013, 2]]}, "inp3:val3": {"data": [[09172013, 10.1], [08172013, 20.0]]}}
    str +='Date,Value'+ '\r\n';
    str +='inp2:val2,'+ '\r\n';
    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp2:val2"].data);
    str +='inp3:val3,'+ '\r\n';
    DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp3:val3"].data);

    function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

       // var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';

            for (var index in array[i]) {
                line += array[i][index] + ',';
            }


            line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }        
    }
 window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str))
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>See the downloaded csv file ....</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var line;
json3["inp2:val2"].data.forEach(function (val, index) {
  line += val[0] + ',' + val[1] + ',';
  line += json3["inp3:val3"].data[index][1] + '\r\n';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try concatenating the two arrays, then pass them through your JSON to CSV method. Then, inside the conversion method, you could created an object with the date as a the key and the paired value would be an array of associated values.

This way, if you were to have more than two associated values, your code is a little more flexible.

Something like this:

```
DownloadJSON2CSV(json3["inp2:val2"].data.concat(json3["inp3:val3"].data));

function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var merged = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var arr = array[i];

        if (!merged[arr[0]]) {
            merged[arr[0]] = [];
        }
        merged[arr[0]].push(arr[1]);
    }

    for (var obj in merged) {
        var line = obj;
        var arr = merged[obj];

        for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            line += ','+arr[i];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
}
```

[Here is a Fiddle as an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/hCmQ9/)